# Fixed size list

Tags: c++, list, templates

I'm writing a FixedSizeList class using a fixed array. I've a problem with the fixed size template parameter, and I'm try to understand if my solution is correct and even how I can solve my problem.

Basically, this is the skeleton of my class:

```
#pragma once

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class SListFixed
{
public:
    SListFixed();

private:
    template <typename T>
    struct Node
    {
        Node(T value)
            :element(value), nextElement(0)
        {
        }

        T element;
        int nextElement;
    };

    Node m_data[N];
    int m_head;
    int m_tail;
    size_t m_elementCounter;
};
```

The first question is on the correctness of this structure. Then I want to understand why this code doesn't compile. Should I make m_data a pointer and allocate that on the stack?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the compiler error message that you are getting?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes.

Comment: @enigma: Then you'd need to show your instantiating this template...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: For example if I call SListFixed<int, 10>. Or you mean the implementation of the constructor?

Comment: Your Node object has no way of knowing what container it is part of, so the next element can't possibly work. Also, why? If you want a linked list, you don't want it backed by an array. That's what vectors are for.

Comment: @Dennis: Presumably, the resolution of next elements is done by the container class, not the inner helper class.

Answer (score 2):

To get this to compile, change

```
Node m_data[N];
```

to

```
Node<T> m_data[N];
```

Because `Node`, after all, is a template class.

That said, simply doing what Oli said and removing the `template <typename T>` from the definition of `Node` will also work because `T` is known from the `FixedSizeList` instantiation. I would recommend doing that because the type of `Node` couldn't ever be different than the type of the `FixedSizeList`.

Though, this answer is so obvious I doubt I'm answering your question. Tell me if I missed something.

Comment: Yes I solved, I had not noticed the lack of default constructor, sorry. And I've also removed the inner template definition.

Comment: @enigma, if you like this answer then you can **accept** it by checking the "right" mark below the points.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say precisely whether this is a good solution, but superficially, it looks ok (compiler errors notwithstanding).  Although I'm not quite sure why you'd want a fixed-size list; isn't the whole point of a list that you can dynamically resize it?  Why not just an array/vector?

As for your compilation problems, you don't need the `template <typename T>` for the inner class; this is already part of a template, and `T` is already known.  Also, you have no default constructor for `Node`, so `Node m_data[N]` won't compile.

Comment: @Oli: This seems to be a classic use of a Non-Type template parameter.  Nothing too strange here.

Comment: @quamrana: I never said that the non-type parameter was an issue!

Comment: @Oli: Is only an exercise, I've already implemented a version that uses std::vector as container and a classic version that uses pointers.

Comment: @Oli: The issue seems to be around the `m_data` member and knowing its size at compile time through the non-type parameter.

Comment: @quamrana: Once I fix the errors I referred to in my answer, I don't get the issue that the OP is complaining about (when I instantiate it as e.g. `SListFixed<int,100> my_list;`).  So there must be something else we don't know about his/her calling code, etc.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Thanks, I've solved. I had not noticed the lack of default constructor, sorry. And then I removed template <typename T>.

Answer (score 0):

A list is by definition a variable size container. Why don't you simply use the [array](http://www.devx.com/cplus/Article/42114/1954) class?

Comment: As I said to Oli Charlesworth, is only an exercise.